# How to write Function to copy tables or data from one schema to another schema in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I tried the following function for copying one table records from one schema table to another schema table.

Is it possible to copy data of one table to another table using functions.

If yes can anyone please share the functions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tds2022.a_transfer_ed_details(
i_finyear integer)
RETURNS TABLE(ed_id integer) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

set search_path to tds2022;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
$q$     
insert into employee_deductee
select * 
from %1$I.employee_deductee where ed_id = 1711578;   

select ed_id from employee_deductee order by ed_id desc limit 1;       
 $q$, 'tds' || i_finyear::text)
 USING i_finyear; 

END;
$BODY$;
```

### Calling Function:

```
select * from tds2022.a_transfer_ed_details(2021);
```

### But I am getting the following error message:

```
 INSERT query does not return tuples
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "
```

### Output Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvDuL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've written this function which fits my requirement..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tds2022.transfer_ed_details(
    i_finyear integer)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
v_cnt int;

BEGIN
EXECUTE 'set search_path =  tds'||i_finyear||';';

    INSERT INTO tds2022.employee_deductee(
        is_emp_ded_flag, entity_id, client_id, branch_id, 
        serial_no, name, name_ref_no, pan, pan_ref_no, address, 
        email_id, pan_verified, deductee_code, designation, 
        employment_from, employment_to, state_code, dob_doi, 
        gender, sc_vsc, name_from_pan, is_transporter, branch,
        ab206_cc, show_in_form, regular_or_correction, correction_flag,
        created_time, created_by_user, modification_time, modified_by_user
       )    
    SELECT 
      is_emp_ded_flag, entity_id, client_id, branch_id, 
      serial_no, name, name_ref_no, pan, pan_ref_no, address,
      email_id, pan_verified, deductee_code, designation, 
      employment_from, employment_to, state_code, dob_doi,
      gender, sc_vsc, name_from_pan, is_transporter, branch,
      ab206_cc, show_in_form, regular_or_correction, correction_flag,
      created_time, created_by_user, now()::timestamp, modified_by_user
      FROM employee_deductee
      ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_employee
      DO UPDATE SET
      modification_time = now()::timestamp;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_cnt = ROW_COUNT;   
     IF (v_cnt) > 0 THEN
     RETURN v_temp_cnt;
     ELSE RETURN 0;
     
     END IF;
     END;
$BODY$;
```